# No output in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm learning JavaScript and I wrote a simple program in Visual Studio Code but there was no output what so ever when I attempted to run it.

```
class main{
    multiplier(x,y){
        return x*y
    }
    main(){
        let x,y
        x = window.prompt('Your favourite number')
        y = window.prompt('Your age')
        console.log(multiplier(x,y))
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: with Ctrl+Alt+N

Comment: You need to call the main method in the main class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did several issues

- didn't create an instance
- didn't run `main()`
- forgot a `this`

```js
class main{
    multiplier(x,y){
        return x*y
    }
    main(){
        let [x, y] = [0, 0]
        x = prompt('Your favourite number')
        y = prompt('Your age')
        console.log(this.multiplier(x,y))
    }
}

const obj = new main()
obj.main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! May I just ask you to link me to a good guide or to explain it to me why and when do we use the this keyword? I'm sorry I'm new to this ;/

Comment: You can mark the answer correct if it's correct and I think this one could be a good start https://codeburst.io/all-about-this-and-new-keywords-in-javascript-38039f71780c

But to put it simply, `this` refers to an object which called this function or accessed variable, but more on that website ;)